# How to get more than two color when i shake my handheld device.My App is on sensor

Tags: android

Hi my app is on sensors and I am not able to find any other color if i shake it.I have provided only two colors in if else loop. But if in want to add some more colors then what should i add. What is the solution.Please help me in this problem.

```
package com.sensortestactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SensorTestActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Boolean color = false;
    private View view;
    private long lastUpdate;

    // -- CALLED WHEN THE ACTIVITY IS FIRST CREATED --//

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        view = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            getAccelerometer(event);
        }

    }

    private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event) {
        float[] values = event.values;

        // -- MOVEMENT --

        float x = values[0];
        float y = values[1];
        float z = values[2];
        float accelerationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
                / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
        long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (accelerationSquareRoot >= 2) {
            if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 200) {
                return;
            }
            lastUpdate = actualTime;
            Toast.makeText(this, "DEVICE WAS SHUFFELED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            if (color) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
            color = !color;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // -- REGISTER THIS CLASS AS A LISTENER FOR THE ORIENTATION AND
        // ACCELEROMETER SENSORS --

        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }
}
```

Comment: How many colors do you want and should they be random or in an order?

Comment: yes if it is random then it is very good.

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```
view.setBackgroundColor(HEXVALUE);
```

The hexvalue is used like this: 0xAARRGGBB

AA = alpha channel
RR = red channel
GG = green channel
BB = blue channel

A valid color would be: 0xFFFF0000 which will create red
Another valid color: 0xFFF0F0F0

for hex numbers you should take a look at wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

You can randomly set the color using a random number generator.

```
Math.random() * 17
```

This will give you integer values starting with 0 and ending at 16. You just need to calc those to hex:
0 = 0

1 = 1

2 = 2

...

9 = 9

10 = A

11 = B

...

16 = F

Comment: but shuld i add this functionality inside the for loop.

Comment: In your code, I don't see a for-loop. You can create a method like getRandomColor() in which you calculate the random color like I explained above. Then you just need to make the following: view.setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor()); after your ToastMessage.